# Java applet in a Delphi form

Tags: java, delphi, applet

Is there any way, without using `TWebBrowser`, to load a java applet in a Delphi form and interact with it?

Theres a page which contains a applet that I want to show inside my Delphi app (in a particular form) and after the user close it (or do any other operation) I want to interact with it (getting some details about what user did).

I know that `TWebBrowser` is capable of loading a java applet, but it will not let me interact and get what I need.

Similar thing can be done with a .Net assembly, but I have not seen anything like it using a java applet.

**Edit:**

As @PA pointed out:

**"it will not let me interact" ... well, that's the actual reason for browsers running java applets inside a sandbox**

**Well .. that was not what a meant. I meant I am not able to get a value from a edit (for example) as I am able to do with other languages. I know that java runs inside a VM, but .Net runs as well and i am able to interact with .Net using some COM and stuff like that.**

Comment: "it will not let me interact" ... well, that's the actual reason for browsers running java applets inside a sandbox.

Comment: It seems you have to interface to the Java plugin to be able to do something like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only way to use Java Applets in Delphi programs wihtout TWebBrowser is to use ActiveX technology. May be this link from google can help you: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-141438.html

Comment: Ok, it seems nice. But can you elaborate your answer, maybe with a small example?

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/beans/axbridge/developerguide/index.html - here you can see a complate instruction how to create activex-controls from applets - this process likely can be automated, after adding created activex-control you can communicate with it in a standart COM-style way

Answer (score 0):

May be you should take a look at Java Native Interface (JNI) technology. For example, you can find its Delphi implementation [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/djbridge/).

Comment: The source code is very old and does not work in Delphi 2010.

Comment: It is sad to hear, the last time I was faced with JNI in Delphi 2006.